# Amazon S3 REST API - resources with space in path

Tags: java, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What is the proper way to treat the case of Amazon S3 resources which contain space in their name (path) ?

I used instructions from [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-examples-using-sdks.html#sig-v4-examples-using-sdk-java), code samples in [the jar file](https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-java-sdk/samples/AWSS3SigV4JavaSamples.jar) that is linked in the article, and they work fine when I GET a resource with a path that contains no spaces, eg: `https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/Folder01/name_WITHOUT_spaces.txt`.
However, exact same code does not work for a resource with spaces in the path, eg: `https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/Foo+1/name+with+space.txt`.

[image]

I tried several ways with/without escaping the space char

- "Foo 1/name with space.txt": The signature builder escapes the space to '+', building something like `Foo+1/name+with+space.txt` and I get the response:

`<Error><Code>HttpVersionNotSupported</Code><Message>The HTTP version specified is not supported.</Message> ...`

- "Foo+1/name+with+space.txt": The signature builder escapes the '+' character building something like `Foo%2B1/name%2Bwith%2Bspace.txt`
- "Foo%201/name%20with%20space.txt": The signature builder escapes **AGAIN** the '%' character, building something like `Foo%25201/name%2520with%2520space.txt`

In both last cases, I get the response:

`<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message> ...`

What am I doing wrong ?
How should I treat / escape the space character ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you google "aws s3 key with spaces" you will find that lots of other people have found frustration with S3 and spaces. I don't know if your answer is in those search results. Our solution is to not use spaces (but obviously, this might not work for you).